# Exact border handling of del2 in opencv laplacian

Tags: matlab, opencv, border

I would like to implement an exact copy of the del2 function in opencv. In particular handling of the border conditions is significantly different.

I am using the laplacian function and using it in opencv gives correct values for the interior points but the borders differ significantly from the matlab version.

Does anyone know how the border can be fixed? I looked at the code for del2 in Matlab and they computer border conditions while computing the inner values. Doing this in opencv would require a complete reimplementation of laplacian which would probably be very inefficient.

Some work around would be great!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you've tried? Have you looked at graphics specific functions?